# ValueError when loading the page with objects without image

Tags: django, django-models

I receive this error after creating a Bb object without image: "The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it."
When I restart the debug server I get the same error until I provide Bb object with an image using django admin panel.

Possible solution I came up with: add default static image: `image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image', null=True, blank=True, default="default.jpg")`
But I want to know why there's an error even when `null=True` and `blank=True` are passed in models.py

models.py:

```
class Bb(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,
     verbose_name='Product', error_messages={'blank' : 'Wrong product name'})
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,
     verbose_name='Description')
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True,
     verbose_name='Current price')
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True,
     verbose_name='Published in')
    # Image
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image', null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

from .forms import BbForm, ImgForm, ImgNonМodelForm
from .models import Bb, Rubric, Img

def index(request):
    bbs = Bb.objects.all()

    # Paginator
    paginator = Paginator(bbs, 4)
    if 'page' in request.GET:
        page_num = request.GET['page']
    else:
        page_num = 1
    page = paginator.get_page(page_num)

    context = {'bbs' : page.object_list, 'page' : page}
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'bboard/index.html', context=context)


def create_bb(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form_bb = BbForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form_images = ImgNonМodelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
        if all([form_bb.is_valid(), form_images.is_valid()]):
            new_bb = form_bb.save()
            # Here I'm saving images from ImgNonModelForm
            for file in request.FILES.getlist('img'):
                img = Img()
                img.desc = form_images.cleaned_data['desc']
                img.img = file
                img.bb = new_bb
                img.save()

            return redirect('/bboard/')
    else:
        form_bb = BbForm()
        form_images = ImgNonМodelForm()

    context = {'form_bb' : form_bb, 'form_images' : form_images}
    return render(request, 'bboard/create_with_images.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

from .models import Bb


class BbForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BbForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Bb
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'price', 'image')
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "layout/basic.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div class="b">
    <h2><a href="{% url 'detail' pk=bb.pk %}">{{ bb.title }}</a></h2>
    <h2>{{ bb.title_with_price }}</h2>
    <p>{{ bb.content }}</p>
    <div>
        {% if bb.image %}
            <div><img src="{{ bb.image|thumbnail_url:'default' }}" alt="Missing image"></div>
        {% else %}
            <p>No image</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <p>{{ bb.published|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</p>
    <h3><a href="{% url 'edit' pk=bb.pk %}">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'delete' pk=bb.pk %}">Delete</a></h3>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div>
{% if page.has_previous %}
<a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">&lt;</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
{% endif %}
Часть №{{ page.number }} из {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}
{% if page.has_next %}
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">&gt;</a>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 62, in url
    self._require_file()
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.9.2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 39, in _require_file
    raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /bboard/
Exception Value: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Comment: Just try only with ```blank=True```

Comment: @Sumithran, unfortunately didn't work for me.

Comment: Still got the same error?

Comment: @Sumithran, Yeah... ValueError: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Okay, how about default='default.jpg'

Comment: If I'm adding default='...' it works with only blank=True and with both params either. With default param this ImageField gets url string (e.g. '#') and i can simply check this in the template: {% if bb.image == '#' %}. But I have a similar model with the same ImageField but without default param and when I'm trying to display it even without actual urls it works fine.

Comment: You seem to have written something like `image.url` somewhere as the stack trace shows that it is called. Perhaps there might be something in the parent template `layout/basic.html`?

Comment: Oh my god, the error was because of a single line of code which was commented:

<!-- <div><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ bb.image.url }}" alt="Missing image" style="max-height:50px"></div> -->

I've commented it previously just to try out some other ways of displaying images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because of a single line of code which was commented:

```
{% extends "layout/basic.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div class="b">
    <h2><a href="{% url 'detail' pk=bb.pk %}">{{ bb.title }}</a></h2>
    <h2>{{ bb.title_with_price }}</h2>
    <p>{{ bb.content }}</p>
    <div>
        

        <!-- The line was here! -->
        <!-- <div><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ bb.image.url }}" alt="Missing image" 
        style="max-height:50px"></div> -->


        {% if bb.image %}
            <div><img src="{{ bb.image|thumbnail_url:'default' }}" alt="Missing image"></div>
        {% else %}
            <p>No image</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <p>{{ bb.published|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</p>
    <h3><a href="{% url 'edit' pk=bb.pk %}">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'delete' pk=bb.pk %}">Delete</a></h3>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`<!-- <div><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ bb.image.url }}" alt="Missing image" style="max-height:50px"></div> -->`

I've commented it previously just to try out some other ways of displaying images and also decided not to include it in this issue.

My gratitude to those who have tried to help me!